# How to handle SOAPFaultException in client

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

In my application we are consuming a SOAP web service. Now we are trying to display an error page when ever the service is down. I have put SOAPFaultException in a catch block where ever there is a web service call and from there I re-directed it to error page which says web services are down. But now I am getting this error page for bad requests to the web service also.
How can I differentiate b/w these bad request and service down exceptions. In both the cases am getting same exception. It's a third party web service.

Comment: The web service that you're consuming is implemented by you or is it a third-party web service?

Comment: My advice is to recreate both exceptions, and check the exceptions' properties.  I see SOAPFaultException has a getFault method that provides a whole series of useful properties you could probably use to determine the cause, specifically getFaultCode.

Comment: @aribeiro it's a third party web sevice.

Comment: Then, and since you can't create a custom `SOAPFaultException` for each case, I'd follow @Neil's advice and act accordingly the fault code of each fault exception.

Comment: How to differentiate based on the fault codes , is there any standard way to send fault codes from web service. We don't know whether it's sending fault code for bad request or service down .

Comment: When you catch your `SOAPFaultException`, you can attain the fault code like this: `yourSoapFaultException.getFault().getFaultCode()`. Then, you should be able to map the different fault codes: one for your bad requests and the other one for your server unavailability.